# Model object reference null in index.cshtml but valid object reference in scaffolded view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working through a simple ASP.NET Core project that implements a basic blog.

Model:

```
namespace Blog.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've used Entity Framework in this project to scaffold CRUD views for a "Posts" endpoint. Here's the controller:

```
namespace Blog.Controllers
{
    public class PostsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public PostsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Posts
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
              return _context.Post != null ? 
                          View(await _context.Post.ToListAsync()) :
                          Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Post' is null.");
        }

        // .. other methods
    }
}
```

The `Posts/Index.cshtml` file was created. This is a simplified version of its contents.

```
@model IEnumerable<Blog.Models.Post>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <p>@item.Title</p>
}
```

This controller/view code works just fine - it prints the titles of all my Blog entries from the database.

Now I want to modify the Home controller and view to do the same thing. Here is my controller (I haven't touched it since I created the project):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // .. other methods
}
```

I've change the `Home/Index.cshtml` to be exactly the same as the `Posts/Index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Blog.Models.Post>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <p>@item.Title</p>
}
```

When I navigate to the URL `/Home`, I get a Null Reference Exception for the `Model` property on the `@foreach` line. Why, and how do I fix it?

Comment: In your controller, how are you passing the model to the view?

Comment: For the scaffolded views, I have left the generated code largely unchanged. It looks like each View has a method that simply returns `View()`.  For the `Home/Index.cshtml` view, I have not added any logic to pass a model to this view. Your comment makes me to think this is a problem, but the generated code doesn't pass the model either...

Comment: If your controller code is `View()`, without anything inside the parentheses, I'd assume that your model would be null. Can you post the controller code? It would be interesting to know how EF sends data to the view.

Comment: @gunr2171 I've appended the controller code to my post. I notice there is some additional logic in the `Index()` method ensuring that the EF database context is not null. This pertains only to `Posts/Index.cshtml` I assume? Could this be why the model reference is null in `Home/Index.cshtml`?

Comment: Some observations/questions as I attempt to figure this out. 1. (assuming this is generated code) not sure why it's doing a null check for `_context.Post` in the `Index` method, I don't see how that could ever be null. 2. I'm assuming `_context.Post` is a `DbSet<>` - one of your DB tables. You may wish to pluralize that name. 3. Add `var posts = await _context.Post.ToListAsync();` to the _beginning_ of your Index method, and put a breakpoint on it. Navigate to the `/Posts` URL and see if the variable is null after you execute the line.

Comment: 4. There is an overload of `View()` that has a string argument for the name of the view. If you don't provide it, then it will search for a View file based on the Controller and Method name. So yes, in your case the default would be "Views/Posts/Index.cshtml".

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. The controller code you've posted is only going to be applicable for the files in the "Views/Posts" folder. It's not going to use the "Views/Home" view files at all. What does the `Index` method in the `HomeController` class look like?

Comment: @gunr2171 the `Index` method in the `HomeControlle.cs` class contains only a `return View();` statement. I have updated my post to contain this code.

Comment: @gunr2171 `_context.Post` is indeed of type `DbSet<Post>`. That null check was generated when I scaffolded my `Post` class to a controller. I chose the naming convention for my `Post` model as singular as it contains properties for a single post, and when scaffolding I created views in a `Posts` (plural) directory so I am not sure why the `Post` member of `_context` is singular.... When I debug as you have suggested, `posts` is not null. This is what I expected because the null object reference only occurs when I try to access the `/Home/Index` view, and it only after changing the boilerplate

Comment: I've shuffled around and simplified your code examples. Can you check it over? If there's an assumption I've incorrectly made please edit or revert it. Maybe you'll be able to spot the problem, if not I'll provide an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I navigate to the URL /Home, I get a Null Reference Exception for
> the Model property on the @foreach line. Why?

Well, based on your scenario and description, within your index view in HomeController, based on your defination `@model IEnumerable<Blog.Models.Post>` and `@foreach (var item in Model)` its means, while calling `/Home` URL it will invoke your Index action and return empty view but according to your Index view code snippet it's expecting a collection of `Post` model which has not been supplied from your view as a result you are getting following error/exception:

[image]

[image]

Conversely, another important point is that, even if you redirect the view from your posts/Index to `Home/Index.cshtml` it will first hit the Home/Index and will search for List as you are not returning anything will ended up with null reference exception as well.

> How do I fix it?

According to your code snippet in HomeIndex view, as you would like to disply the collection of Post which is IEnumerable<Blog.Models.Post> so from your controller, you should return the List. So you just need to update your Index action as following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Post.ToListAsync());
        }
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to official document for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0)